# Regex match where the following word not presence

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to match a sentence where it started with "(Brand)" then not followed by  "OTP"

For example

**(Brand)Anything other** will return TRUE
**(Brand)OTP** will return FALSE

Comment: Try `\(Brand\)(?!OTP)`, maybe preceded by `^`  if must match at the very start of the input.